# Testing a diode's electrical characteristics with temperature control

Tags: diodes, peltier, testing, device-characteristics

I would like to test a few diodes electrical characteristics at their device low limit, ambient, and device high limit temperatures.

I was thinking of using a Peltier element with a heat sink, but I'm not too sure how this would look like with sending current pulses.

The Peltier element could be put in a thermal chamber, but wouldn't the length of test leads cause interference with impedance and such?

The diodes of test are listed here:

[MBRS340T3G](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MBRS340T3-D.PDF)
[MBRS360T3G](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MBRS360T3-D.PDF)
[BSS123](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/BSS123-D.PDF)
[MBRS130LT3G](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MBRS130LT3-D.PDF)
[MBRS3200T3G](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MBRS3200T3-D.PDF)

Comment: Are you looking for a solution for inbound test or simply want to test a few hand selected components?

Comment: inbound test. Does my question make sense or do I need to clarify further?

Comment: Do you have a TEC controller to provide the correct current to the Peltier device depending on feedback from a temperature sensor? Which one are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure if I have one at work, but I would assume no. If I can provide a set up using a TEC Controller at a reasonable price, I could try to get permission to purchase the TEC controller and peltier element.                                                                                            I just didn't want to buy anything prior to finalizing on a working test set up.

Answer (score 1):

If you are anticipating an inbound test environment (hundreds to thousands of devices) then I assume you want to test in tape/reel mount with pin probes.
I'd suggest:

1. Ambient tests simply at room temperature
2. Room temperature environment High temperature test using self heating (perhaps use a thermal imager to measure temperature if you want close spec)
3. Low temperature testing may be the largest challenge, but perhaps you could use a compressed air cooler. These can get you to -40 degC (with pre-cooled air supply) and I've used them for high power cpu tests with no heatsinks, holding a cpu at about 0 DegC. for example [Exair cold gun](http://www.exair.com/index.php/products/cold-gun-aircoolant-systems/cold-gun-sys1.html)

If you are testing complete reels, then of course you could use a small environmental chamber, fitting your reel to reel testing station inside.

The use of a peltier is possible, though I think it would slow your testing rate.

Comment: I apologize, I was not familiar with the term inbound test. I am just sampling 5-6 of each of the above listed diodes.

Comment: the low/high limit temps for the diodes are around -55C to 125C. Is this realistic from a Peltier element?

Comment: You certainly can achieve 125 degC, though likely with 2 in series (thermally) but achieving -55 degC may be more of a challenge. Most modules are only rated to -40 degC.  https://tetech.com/peltier-thermoelectric-cooler-modules/high-temperature/

Comment: Honestly as long as I can get relatively close to the low limit temperature of the diodes, that will work perfectly. Thanks for the link!

Comment: I will look into options as to how to cascasde two of them. Thanks Jack

Comment: use dry ice to get -50 C

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Dry Ice is -78degC, managing to get an accurate -50 is hard.

Comment: -78’C is really hard as the gas released is an insulator, a heat sink is necessary with vibration to release gas then an external powered air stirrer -50~-55’C is possible using crushed dry ice on the heat sink.